# What makes x = 2 machine independent vs MOV X , 2?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction

From *Compiler Construction* (Louden):

> Assembly language is extremely dependent on the particular machine for which it was written, so code written for one computer must be completely rewritten for another machine. Clearly, the next major step in programming technology was to write the operations of a program in a concise form more nearly resembling mathematical notation or natural language, in a way that was independent of any one particular machine and yet capable of itself being translated by a program into executable code. For example, the assembly code `MOV X, 2` can be written in a concise, machine-independent form as `x = 2`

I don't understand—I guess I'm missing his point. If modern programming languages used `MOV X, 2` instead of `x = 2`, how would that make them any less machine-independent? A compiler would still have to translate either statement into a machine code equivalent, wouldn't it?

Comment: C is portable assembly ;) If you allowed significant translation of the program, it wouldn't be assembly anymore. The point of assembly is to be a close representation of machine instructions that is easier for a human to use. As such, what instructions you can use depends on the particular architecture and is not portable.

Comment: @Jester I see, thanks.

Comment: x86 AT&T syntax would use `mov $2, x`.  x86 NASM syntax would use `mov [x], 2`.  x86 MASM syntax would use `mov x, 2`.  (Assuming `x` is a global / static variable.  If it's currently live in a register, then the destination would be whatever register).  Some machines don't even really *have* a `mov` instruction.  e.g. MIPS does mov-immediate with an or-immediate with the zero-register, placing the result in a different dest reg, because like more RISC machines, ALU instructions are 3-operand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example `MOV X, 2` assumes that *MOV* is a hardwired CPU instruction. It loads *2* into register *X*.
You are right that a parser could translate `MOV X, 2` into any other language. In fact, the assembler does parse and translate it into machine language, which is just a stream of *0* and *1*.

`x=2` on the other hand side does not resemble machine instructions. It is a typical syntax found in higher level languages.

Comment: So if I take your meaning, you're saying that assembly instructions reflect the architecture of the machine, whereas higher-level instructions are "abstract" (simply specifying what to do)? Is that it?